# google chrome preview ajax not working

Tags: ajax

I'm working on my project but I don't get error logs of my ajax in google chrome. Somebody know how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the ajax code you wrote? It seems you are not returning data in the proper format

Comment: My classmate can see errors on huis MacBook and i can’t on Windows so there is data returning. This is my Ajax code